# Splitting a String like the linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, string, parsing, split

I have a string like 'abc \'abc\' "123" 12\\'3'.

What I want to do is parse it up like the Unix terminal would. Is there some way to do this without dealing with complex regexes?

Example:
`java -jar foo.jar abc 'abc' "123" 12\'3`

Would become this array of Strings `["abc","abc","123","12'3"]`

Is there any sort of library / functionality built into Java that would allow me to do this?

Comment: have you checked [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))? Will that work for you?

Comment: One library which can do that for you is parboiled. You'd need to write a grammar (in Java!), but it's pretty simple.

Comment: @Smit consider that `azek"dd"'\''eio\"\'` is a valid token (which ultimately is `azekdd'eio"'`

Comment: You seem to want to get the options of your program. In C, there is a function getopt() for that purpose. In java, there are some libraries which do the same.

Comment: @adenoyelle that is not the problem here: OP wants to _parse a string like the shell would_, he does not have the arguments

Comment: @Smit Nope. It required advanced regex, which I really would prefer not to sit down and work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write your own parser (and for simplification, I'd recommend you use Guava and its `CharMatcher` to match characters) or use an existing parser library. My personal favorite is [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) since you can write your grammars *in Java*.

For instance, this very crude grammar splits into words which only contains letters (note however my parboiled-fu is a little rusty):

```
Rule Spaces()
{
    return OneOrMore(AnyOf(" \t"));
}

Rule Letter()
{
    return Range('a', 'z');
}

Rule Word()
{
    return OneOrMore(IgnoreCase(Letter());
}

Rule OneLine()
{
    // EOI == End Of Input
    return Sequence(Optional(Spaces()), Word(),
        ZeroOrMore(Sequence(Spaces(), Word()), EOI);
}
```

There is a stack you can push values to etc so that you get the list of all strings eventually.